# How do I show the Begin/End of async method in SoapUI tool

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, soapui

I implemented an async method by WCF.

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
IAsyncResult BeginRequestUser(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

string EndRequestUser(IAsyncResult result);
```

I am using SoapUI to test this service but when I add wsdl to SoapUI, I only see that have only one service with name RequestUser.

[image]

My expectation is in SoapUI, I will see 2 services BeginRequestUser and EndRequestUser.

**Question:** How do I show Begin/End of async method in SoapUI ?

Comment: You mean the time?

Comment: I don't understand your question, please details that.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want the stand and end of the request and response?

Comment: yes, I want in soapUI, I have 2 services, start.. it is request method and end... it is response method.